# Data is not updated despite status 200 - rest assured

Tags: java, rest, automated-tests, rest-assured, web-api-testing

I'm trying to send put request to trello api (https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/trello/rest/api-group-organizations/#api-organizations-id-put). I've got response with status 200 but data is not updated. Here is my request:

```
@Test(priority = 1)
public void updateOrganization() {
    JSONObject organization = new JSONObject();
    organization.put("displayName", "org");
    organization.put("name", "test123");

    Response response = given()
            .spec(reqSpec)
            .queryParam("organizationId", organizationId)
            .body(organization)
            .when()
            .put("https://api.trello.com/1/organizations" + "/" + organizationId)
            .then()
            .statusCode(200)
            .extract()
            .response();

    JsonPath json = response.jsonPath();
    System.out.println(response.asString());
    organizationId = json.getString("id");
    organizationName = json.getString("name");
    Assert.assertEquals(organizationName, "test123");
}
```

And here is response:

```
{"id":"60db4c31ff40b31e7ce3591f","name":"test95159884","displayName":"organization","descData":{"emoji":{}},"website":null,"teamType":null,"desc":"","url":"https://trello.com/test95159884","logoHash":null,"logoUrl":null,"products":[],"powerUps":[]}
```

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that when you call the API using above code, the final URL will be:

```
"https://api.trello.com/1/organizations/{organizationId}?organizationId={organizationId}"
```

In the API docs, the request just need `organizationId` as Path parameter, not Query Parameter.

My suggesstion is removing the code:

```
.queryParam("organizationId", organizationId)
```